Player is accessed on the wrong thread in React-Native (Expo)
I have been trying to found a solution for the error i am getting. I have minimized the code and running it in the main screen for testing but still getting error.
Running in android emulator (Android 13) inside Expo and i get the error below when reloading the app.
Error
Player is accessed on the wrong thread.
Current thread: 'mqt_native_modules'
Expected thread: 'main'
See https://exoplayer.dev/issues/player-accessed-on-wrong-thread

My code (minimized for testing)
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

    useEffect(() => {
        const sound = new Audio.Sound();
    
        const loadAndPlaySound = async () => {
            try {
                await sound.loadAsync(require('../../sounds/app_notification.mp3'));
                await sound.playAsync();
                console.log('Sound played successfully');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error loading or playing sound:', error);
            }
        };
    
        loadAndPlaySound();
    
        return () => {
            const unloadSound = async () => {
                try {
                    await sound.unloadAsync();
                    console.log('Sound unloaded successfully');
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error unloading sound:', error);
                }
            };
    
            unloadSound();
        };
    }, []);

Output
LOG  Sound loaded successfully
ERROR  Error unloading sound: [Error: Player does not exist.]


I'm experiencing this on Expo 51. It worked fine on Expo 50

@Odunsi I have tried in different ways to avoid this but it feels like a bug, have you found any way to get around the error?

no, not yet. better to open an issue on GitHub

Expo has a new video component now but it's still in beta. I tried it and I don't get this error anymore. You can give it a try too.

@Odunsi If you check my problem it is regarding audio and not video. thanks anyway though.

Same here ... But it "only" (but always !) happens when I refresh the app !
